# How to Retrieving Html generated by JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, shopping-cart, cart, console.log

I want to retrieve cart product list ,which is on an html generated by JavaScript. I tried  `var input = console.log(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML)` this returns a value of `undefined` . Please help

Comment: It returns a value of `undefined` because `console.log()` doesn't return anything. Open your JS-Console and try it out, http://i.imgur.com/D6Cu9UH.jpg

Comment: Do the elements have an ID or a class? Try getElementByID or getElementsByClassname

Comment: you want receive a value from console???

Comment: Either remove `var input =` or remove `console.log()`. As @LucaKiebel points out, the return of `console.log()` will *always* be `undefined`.

Answer (score 2):

You're getting undefined because you are a little mixed up in your statements. `console.log` will log whatever is encased in the parenthesis to the browser console. So in this case, you have your var input executing a console log which logically doesn't make much sense. But you're close...

You can do something among the lines of:

```
var input = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML;
console.log(input);
```

And this will print the HTML contents of the first element with the html tag.

Comment: `console.log()` will only output to the console of the browser. It won't print anything to the window or anywhere in the DOM. Are you looking at the console output?

Comment: I want to get html added by JavaScript , this is  a list of products created on click in a cart "

Comment: Are you executing this `getElementsByTagName` code after the list of products are already in the cart? If you are creating these cart products using JavaScript, could you not reference their variables within JavaScript instead of getting them from HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Console.log doesn't return values from its function, it just prints stuff to the terminal. When functions are undefined that means you didn't provide a return value.

example:

```
function addTwoNumbers( val1, val2 ) {
  const str = 'Adding two numbers';
  return val1 + val2;
}
```

will return whatever the result of number val1 added onto a number val2 is. If you remove the return val1 + val2 statement, the str variable will just get ignored because its not being returned, therefore the result of function addTwoNumbers(); will become undefined.

Comment: How do I retrieve html generated by JavaScript then ?